# skypeforlinux-64.deb doesn't support default sound settings and goes white when call is connected

Tags: sound, compiz, pulseaudio, skype, microphone

I have the below skype installed on my Ubuntu - 14.04.

It goes white when the call is connected.

I read somewhere, `Compiz` is also causing this issue, I am using `Compiz` too

Following are my current settings, I tried a lot of combinations of them, none worked.  I doubt this because, with every change in these settings, a start of the white screen is delayed.

**Version**
[image: Version information]

**Microphone settings**
[image: Microphone settings]

**Speakers Settings**
[image: Speakers settings]

**System settings output**
[image: System Settings output]

**System settings input**
[image: System Settings input]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what changed now, but I observed when I talk, a screen was going white. so I tried playing with microphone settings and `USB PnP Sound Device, USB Audio` worked.